# How to find entries which has not empty StringListProperty?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have a following model in the Google appengine app.

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
  names = db.StringListProperty(required=False)
```

So, I want to get entries which has not empty in names property. I tried like this.

```
TestModel.all().filter('names !=', [])
```

But it raises the exception: **BadValueError: Filtering on lists is not supported**

How can I filter it? or Should I check one by one like following?

```
for entry in TestModel.all():
  if len(entry.names) > 0:
     result.append(entry)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`TestModel.all().filter('names >=', None)`

This will give you every entity with at least one value set for names, i.e. every value in the index.