# How can I find entities which have an empty StringListProperty?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Given this model:

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
  names = db.StringListProperty(required=False)
```

I want to find entities that have an empty names property, so I tried this:

```
TestModel.all().filter('names ==', [])
```

But it raises the exception: **BadValueError: Filtering on lists is not supported**

From [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839125/how-to-find-entries-which-has-not-empty-stringlistproperty), I also tried:

```
TestModel.all().filter('names <', None)
TestModel.all().filter('names ==', None)
```

But these did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

Filtering on lists filters against each item in the list.  So if you filter('names ==', 'x'), it'll find any entity that contains 'x' in the names list.

Unfortunately, you can't find an empty list this way.  Your best bet is to add another property to test model, either an integer for the list size, or a boolean value isEmpty, and query against that instead.